# Robots.txt http://example.com vs.http:// www.example.com

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I have a situation where we have two code bases that need to stay intact..

example: `http://example.com`.

And a new site `http://www.example.com`.

The old site (no WWW) supports some legacy code and has the rule:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

But in the new version (with WWW) there is no `robots.txt`.

Is Google looking to the old (no WWW) `robots.txt` file as its rule?  And will adding

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

to the (WWW) side override this?

Changing `robots.txt` on in the old codebase is not an option at this time.

Answer (score 2):

No, the subdomain "www." and the subdomain "" are separate subdomains, and the `robots.txt` from one of them is not used for the other.